# Codeigniter inserts empty value, default value of table field in MySQL is ignored

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, default

I'm doing an insert to a table, some data is empty so I expect some fields to get the default value I assigned.

```
$data = array(
            'id'            => $id,
            'user'       => $this->input->post('name'),
            );

$this->the_model->the_model_funciton($data);
```

The problem is with the user field, the default value for the field is 'Anon' but when there's no data in the post('name') an empty value is inserted instead of the default value in the field.

User field is varchar, null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would this do it?

```
$data = array(
           'id'   => $id
       );

if ($user = $this->input->post('name')) {
   $data['user'] = $user;
}
```

Comment: I get an error "Can't use method return value in write context in line xx"

Comment: @Alex, I still see an empty value being inserted and not the default field value :-(

Comment: That did the trick :)
But let's suppose I have 10 or 20 fields that need to get the default value as well, I need do this for each input? is this a normal behavior with the post method in Codeigniter?

Comment: @Danny: TBH I have never used CodeIgniter :) If passing `NULL` does not work, this may be your only option, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably related to the `post` method. When `name` is empty or undefined it will return an empty string. Which then gets input in the column.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$default_user = "Anon";
$username = $this->input->post('name');
if($username == empty) ? $username = $default_user : $this->input->post('name'));
$data = array(
            'id'            => $id,
            'user'       => $this->input->post('name'),
            );

$this->the_model->the_model_function($data);
```

Comment: if(empty($username)) ? $username = $default_user : $this->input->post('name'));